# What wrong when try to translate this output code

Tags: php

How I can translate the output of this code:

```
<b>N. di pagine:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]["pages"]}<br>
<b>Tipo:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['color']}<br>
<b>Formato:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['paper_size']}<br>
<b>Orientamento:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['orientation']}<br>
<b>Fronte/Retro:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['print_type']}<br>
<b>Copie:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['copies']}<br><br>
```

I have try edit the code in thi way:

```
<b>Colore:</b> if($_SESSION["printDetails"]["color"]=="bw"){echo "Bianco/Nero"; } else{echo "Colori";}<br>
```

but nothing!

The HTML code is already inside a PHP code:

```
if (mysql_query($query)) {
            $msg = "Done";
            // send message to admin regarding printing information //
            $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 'admin'";
            $res = mysql_query($queryStr);
            $adminDetails = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $emailContent = "Caro admin, <br><br>
                            Hai una nuova richiesta di stampa da <b><i>{$userDetails["user_name"]}</i></b>. Ecco i dettagli: <br><br>
                            <b>N. di pagine:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]["pages"]}<br>
                            <b>Tipo:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['color']}<br>
                            <b>Formato:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['paper_size']}<br>
                            <b>Orientamento:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['orientation']}<br>
                            <b>Fronte/Retro:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['print_type']}<br>
                            <b>Copie:</b> {$_SESSION["printDetails"]['copies']}<br><br>
                            Grazie, <br>
                            -WeScriba team";
            sendEmail($adminDetails['user_email_address'], "Nuova richiesta di stampa", $emailContent);
        } else {
            $msg = "notsaved";
        }
```

Comment: What kind of template engine are you using? You may need to check how to have `if` conditions.

Comment: Where are the php tags ??

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't use the old, deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Create your if-statements before the string and put the results in variables or an array and use that in your string instead. You can't have PHP-statements in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the PHP tags `<?php` and `?>` to denote that you are swapping between HTML and PHP:

```
<b>Colore:</b>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION["printDetails"]["color"] == "bw") {
        echo "Bianco/Nero";
    } else {
    echo "Colori";
    }
    ?>
<br>
```

Or output the HTML from within the PHP code itself, making use of `echo`:

```
<?php
    echo "<b>Colore:</b>";
    if($_SESSION["printDetails"]["color"] == "bw") {
        echo "Bianco/Nero";
    } else {
    echo "Colori";
    }
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: It may work, but if he is using some template engine this is not the best way to go.

Comment: Its using placeholders in php, nothing special { }